# Remove substring between two characters

Tags: java, regex

How can I remove substring between two characters(`+` and `@`).
Ex-

`bunny+12kl@funny.com` should give `bunny@funny.com`

Which regex I should use for this.

Comment: is there just one occurrence, or do you want to remove all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String s = "bunny+12kl@funny.com";
String email = s.replaceAll("\\+.*@", "@");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

`str = str.replaceAll("\\+[^@]*@", "@");`

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "bunny+12kddddd+++ddd/d/d/d/d\\####ddl@funny.com";
        str = str.replaceAll("\\+[^@]*@", "@");
        System.out.println(str);        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex it is:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("(.*?)[+].*?(@.*)", "$1$2");
```

Though you can completely avoid regex and use `String#indexOf` methods to find 2 positions and get substrings using that.

Comment: Try this "$1@$2" for replacement.

Comment: Fxed it. Actually I intended to keep `@` in brackets but mistyped it.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = s.replace(s.substring(s.indexOf("+"), s.indexOf("@")), "");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a regex.  You can do it just using a for loop:

```
for(;;) {
    int start = str.indexOf('+');
    if(start == -1) break;
    int stop = str.indexOf('@');
    if(stop == -1) break;
    str = str.substring(0,start+1) + str.substring(stop);
}
```

This is more verbose, but may explain better to others maintaining the code later what it is you meant to do.  Not everyone is comfortable decoding regex.

Comment: I agree with you, and regex might take more process times than expected. This is a more elegant solution. You can change it to single line if you prefer. str = str.substring(0,str.indexOf('+')+1) + str.substring(str.indexOf('@')+1,str.length);

Comment: @ScriptShiva yes, very elegant although I was trying to spell it out so as to document the aim clearer.  If you want to replace them all, you need some kind of exit check in a loop anyways.

Comment: I meant this is not better than a small regex here. Maybe you got it the other way around.

Comment: @peter.petrov its interesting that there are so many different regex that people are suggesting.  It really feels almost like a https://xkcd.com/208/ moment ;)  As I said, not everyone is comfortable decoding regex.  Spare a thought for the maintenance code who follows in your footsteps.

Comment: I get your point completely but the regex expressions which the people suggest here are no longer than 10-15 chars. If you're saying this is too complex to maintan, than I guess you're saying we should not use regex at all. If it was a regexp that's longer I would be on your opinion. Anyway, this is just an opinion based question we're discussing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using RegExp grouping.

```
String str = "bunny+12kl@funny.com";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+?)\\+.*@(.+?)$");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1) +matcher.group(2));
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just write a utility class to slice Strings:

```
public class MyStringUtils {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String str = "bunny+12kl@funny.com";
        int startIndex = str.indexOf('+');
        int endIndex = str.indexOf('@');

        System.out.println("Outer: " + sliceRangeOuter(str, startIndex, endIndex));
        System.out.println("Inner: " + sliceRangeInner(str, startIndex, endIndex));
    }

    public static String sliceStart(String str, int startIndex) {
        if (startIndex < 0)
            startIndex = str.length() + startIndex;
        return str.substring(startIndex);
    }

    public static String sliceEnd(String str, int endIndex) {
        if (endIndex < 0)
            endIndex = str.length() + endIndex;
        return str.substring(0, endIndex);
    }

    public static String sliceRangeInner(String str, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        if (startIndex < 0)
            startIndex = str.length() + startIndex;
        if (endIndex < 0)
            endIndex = str.length() + endIndex;
        return str.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    }

    public static String sliceRangeOuter(String str, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        if (startIndex < 0)
            startIndex = str.length() + startIndex;
        if (endIndex < 0)
            endIndex = str.length() + endIndex;
        return sliceEnd(str, startIndex) + sliceStart(str, endIndex);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Outer: bunny@funny.com
Inner: +12kl
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string input) {
  Regex r = new Regex("(?:[^a-z0-9 ]|(?<=['\"])s)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
  return r.Replace(input, String.Empty);
}
```

Comment: using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Comment: This question is on Java not on C#.